# Why does this Python code output its search results twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have the following tutorial code in Python 3:

```
import sqlite3

connection_string = r"D:\Python\Mega Course\Database\books.db"

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect(connection_string)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, author TEXT, year INTEGER, isbn TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def search(title="", author="", year="", isbn=""):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(connection_string)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?", (title, author, year, isbn))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

connect()
print(search(author="John Smith"))
```

When I run the above script, I get an output of 2 lists:

```
[(3, 'Thee Sea', 'John Smith', '', '')]
[(3, 'Thee Sea', 'John Smith', '', '')]
```

I can't understand or find more than 1 call to `print`. Why is the single row found by `search` output to the console twice?

Comment: What's the content of the database? what happens when you run this query manually (e.g. in sqlite3 on the command line).

Comment: And also - where can one find this database? I can try to debug this.

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you running it inside an IDE or similar, e.g. IDLE? Possibly, one line of output is from the print function, and the other line is echoed from the IDE itself (similar to what the Python promp itself does). Arguably, there is no returned result in the last line, but I don't know how most IDEs behave.

Comment: @Roy2012 I have other code that queries and prints all records in the database, so I know there is only one row.

Comment: @00 I think you may be onto something. I am running the script in the Terminal in VS Code.

Comment: It's easy to test, I think: just add a single `print("test")` call at the very end. If you see that twice, you know it's not the SQL query, but really the print function which result gets echoed. Then try with a lone "test" string at the bottom of your script (which shouldn't do anything), and so on.